# Is there an Android equivalent for iPhone's "mobileconfig"?

Tags: email, ios

iPhone provides an easy way to add Email accounts using .mobileconfig files, "installable configuration profiles" or whatever they call it. Its basically a XML file containing all the parameters needed to install the Email account, its extremely handy.

But I'm in need of something similar for Android. Any ideas?

Or perhaps something I can configure in my server that makes Android detect the technical stuff automatically, like the IMAP and SMTP server/port etc. Google is not being helpful on this.

Answer (score 2):

Nope, unfortunately there is nothing like this to my knowledge.I'd love to be proven wrong though